# How to create PMD custom rule in ruleset?

Tags: java, plugins, pmd

I am damm confusing to create a new PMD rule in ruleset! 
can anyone guide me to the approach to do so?
thanks in advance!

Comment: *I am damm confusing* That made my day, thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Where do you have a problem, in the official documentation?

- [Introduction to writing PMD Rules](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_extending_writing_rules_intro.html)
- [Making Rulesets](https://docs.pmd-code.org/latest/pmd_userdocs_making_rulesets.html)

Comment: yes, all the documentation has not given clear idea to create a new rule in ruleset. I am planning to create rule for comments and javadoc. But unable to create it..! any idea?

Comment: I am planning to do like following for a rule that is 'java comments'.

Comment: I have choosen the existed ruleset from pmd and i was modified message, description, priority and implemented class name. 
Now i am readu to develop a class for checking code to identify the the java comments syntaxes. Here i stopped my implementation due to lack of idea! Any idea on pmd rule for java comments?

Comment: I m successfully able to create PMD custom/new rules in myeclipse IDE. I have created new rules for checking the initializations of integer numbers and some more. But now d problem is, i just want to create rule for checking javadoc, java comments, whitespaces and indentations. have any idea?

Comment: it looks like both of these links are now broken

Answer (score 0):

You can use the designer to write own rules. Below articles might help you.

https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/10/customize-pmd-in-eclipse-with-your-own.html

https://pmd.github.io/latest/pmd_userdocs_extending_designer_reference.html